# Laravel 8: How to insert unique data from the DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I need to insert some unique content into the DB using Laravel 8. Here is my code:

```
foreach($trigger as $e)
{
    if(is_array($e))
    {
        foreach($e as $t)
        $query = DB::table('tickets')->insert([
            'userId' => '',
            'types' => '',
            'startRound' => '',
            'endRound' => '',
            'numbers' => '0x'.$t->toHex() // MUST BE UNIQUE
        ]);
    }
}
```

As you can see the field `numbers` should stored unique numbers but I have some duplicated `Hex` values and I don't want to store them at the DB.

So how can I insert UNIQUE values into the DB.

Note that I have already added unique() to the Migration like this:

`$table->string('numbers')->unique();`

But this does not solve my problem, I need some codes to be added to the Controller for making this field unique.

So I would really appreciate any idea or solution from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1**:

[image]

**UPDATE #2**:

[image]

**UPDATE #3**:

[image]

Comment: do you need to update the row in case of duplicate value or not insert at all?

Comment: @MehravishTemkar I just need insertion

Comment: What do you want to happen when a value is not `unique`? Do you want a `unique` value generated automatically, or just return an error response or some sort?

Comment: @Peppermintology Now I have some random values but some of the values are duplicated and I don't want them to inserted

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to happen if a `number` value is duplicate and is not inserted. Do you want to skip over that insertion or do you want to create a new `number` automatically and insert it?

Comment: @Peppermintology No just skip it

Comment: @Peppermintology I would really appreciate if you share your solution about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to get details of existing data and then before inserting you need to check if the data already exists else insert.

```
$existing_data = DB::table('tickets')->pluck('numbers', 'numbers');

foreach($trigger as $e)
{
    if(is_array($e))
    {
        foreach($e as $t) {
            if(!isset($existing_data['0x'.$t->toHex()])) {
                $query = DB::table('tickets')->insert([
                        'userId' => '',
                        'types' => '',
                        'startRound' => '',
                        'endRound' => '',
                        'numbers' => '0x'.$t->toHex() // MUST BE UNIQUE
                ]);
                $existing_data['0x'.$t->toHex()] = '0x'.$t->toHex();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To reduce the number of rows in `$existing_data`, you can pass all the values of `$t` in your `$trigger` by fetching them through some built-in function and then passing them to the query like this

```
$existing_data = DB::table('tickets')->whereIn('numbers', $all_values_of_t)->pluck('numbers', 'numbers');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tested this and duplicated data still will be added. I just added an **UPDATE #1** about this and u can see duplicated data inserted!

Comment: try dd($existing_data) after $existing_data = DB::table('tickets')->pluck('numbers'); and check if the keys are the values of the numbers column, basically you just need the data indexed with the numbers column

Comment: Plz would u check out **UPDATE 3**

Comment: please update this code $existing_data = DB::table('tickets')->pluck('numbers', 'numbers');

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to skip over the insertion, you could make use of the [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) rule available in the Laravel validator.

```
foreach($trigger as $e) {
    if(is_array($e)) {
        foreach($e as $t) {
            $validator = Validator::make(['number' => '0x'.$t->toHex()], [
                'numbers' => ['unique:tickets'],
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                continue;
            }

            $query = DB::table('tickets')->insert([
                'userId' => '',
                'types' => '',
                'startRound' => '',
                'endRound' => '',
                'numbers' => '0x'.$t->toHex() // MUST BE UNIQUE
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, string given, called ` error

Comment: @KKKKKK Apologies, missed some `[ ]` brackets on the second argument for the `make` method. Updated my answer.

Comment: I tested this, and duplicated data added to the DB. See **UPDATE #2** plz

Comment: @KKKKKK Not having a good morning. I had the `make` parameters the wrong way around.

Comment: the problem with validator in this case is that it will hit the database everytime in the loop to check if the value is unique or not, that would be too many queries on the database

Comment: @MehravishTemkar Indeed. The alternative is your solution where you `pluck` the numbers from the database and hold them all in memory which could be a lot. Both have negatives, it is down to the OP to determine which they prefer.

Comment: yeah i also thought about it, just one column in array but the data could be large, if your code solves his problem i think after a point of time the validator would be a lot more efficient than checking value in array

Comment: @MehravishTemkar Agreed, your solution will be more performant on a smaller data set. Down to the OP to profile the options.  :)

Answer (score 0):

you should  unique method in migration or  in mysql

```
$table->string('field_name')->unique();
```

that will avoid duplicate records